# Tomcat 7 Manager - Commands disabled

Tags: tomcat

I setup Tomcat7 on Debian squeeze.
I changed tomcat-users.xml to contain a role "manager-gui" and a user with this role.

When I log onto the manager web admin, the deploy/undeploy commands as well as deployed applications are not displayed.

In spite of that, I have a message : "Host Manager installed - commands disabled". This happens with apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-admin, as well as with downloading and installing manually.

Additionnaly, this Tomcat is behind an Nginx server which proxy-passes the requests.

Does anyone know how to get these commands working ?

Comment: Are you trying to use the "manager" or the "host-manager"?

Answer (score 1):

The most common mistake when setting up Tomcat's manager webapp is not *uncommenting* the entries in `conf/tomcat-users.xml`. Take care to remove the XML comments (`<--` and `-->`) as appropriate.

Comment: Since he is able to logon to manager web admin, I don't think this has got to do with uncommenting of the tomcat-users in tomcat-users.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, so I'd assume it's probably no longer an issue.. But for future reference: the page being described in the question is the "Virtual Host Manager" page, not the "Web Application Manager" page.

- `http://<server>/host-manager/html/` - Virual Host Manager
- `http://<server>/manager/html/` - Web Application Manager