# Tomcat host manager error: Host Manager installed commands disabled

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat webserver that is hosting 3 webapps. I want to stop only one of them without stopping the whole server. So I am accessing Tomcat Virtual Host Manager (url-prefix/host-manager/html). That shows me all three hosts. For two of the three it's showing a "Stop" and "Remove" button, however for the third app it's showing the following message instead:

```
Host Manager installed - commands disabled
```

What is going wrong? There are no differences in the configuration of these applications in server.xml. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744804/tomcat-7-manager-commands-disabled) but that doesn't apply to me because the "user" line in tomcat-users.xml is indeed uncommented. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to access the host-manager at all, I guess. BTW I'm running Tomcat 7.